# How can you set a validation rule for a field to accept only 0.5 increments (Access 2010)

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

This may be an easy answer but I am stumped as to how I can validate a number field for only allowing 0.5 - 180.0  but only allowing in 0.5 increments.  You can do this with regular expressions in other software but I can't find a formulae to use in the  access table validation rules.

A company wants to enter half days and whole day increments into a work form to prevent quarter days etc..

sorry if this is a noob question.

Edit: Obviously you can use modulus 0.5 ==0  but if fails to work for some reason.

Comment: Single or Decimal e.g:-  1.0 - 180.0  maximum is 180 days (3.5 days)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The validation rule

```
(([YourField]*10) Mod 5)=0 And [YourField]>=0 And [YourField]<=180
```

should work.  No VBA needed

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works, so it was throwing an error on decimals

Comment: With the addition of the requirement that the values be between 0.5 and 180.0, this validation rule is the right approach. But in general, when you're using a floating point data type, you need to be careful with expressions like `[YourField]*10`. These won't behave like you expect with very large values.

Comment: @mike that's true, but if it were needing any more precise the recommendation would be to use the `currency` data type when doing this

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple VBA test.

```
Function Pt5(N As Single) As Boolean
    Pt5 = Not (N * 10) Mod 5
End Function
```

Where N = the number your testing. The reason for multiplying by 10 is that Mod doesn't like decimals.

Comment: Thanks for that I didn't realise that it throwing an error because of a decimal issue.